# How to nest code block under a list item in BitBucket mark down?

Tags: markdown, bitbucket

While there are several questions/answers with combination of keywords from this question, I don't see one that directly asks the same question or answers it.

I want to nest a code block under a list item. When I follow this [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/3793), I don't quite get the effect I'm looking for. In below image, I wouldn't want the leading spaces in the code block and I would like the box itself to be indented under the list item. How do I achieve this?

[image]

And, here is the actual MD:

````
** Help Page **

* This is a list item that has a code block going with it

```
#!c#
        try
        {
            DoSomething(passThis, andThis);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.Log();
        }

```
````

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Instead of a fenced code block (```` ``` ````), use an indented code block. Indent with four spaces to nest inside the list item, and four more to represent a code block:

```
**Help Page**

* This is a list item that has a code block going with it

        #!c
        try
        {
            DoSomething(passThis, andThis);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.Log();
        }
```

Note that the language tag here should be `#!c`, not `#!c#` as in your question.

Alternatively, you can use a fenced code block but it must still be indented by four spaces so it gets included in the list item:

````
**Help Page**

* This is a list item that has a code block going with it

    ```c
    try
    {
        DoSomething(passThis, andThis);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.Log();
    }
    ```
````

Comment: @red888, can you be more specific? Please review [ask].

Comment: My comment can be ignored. I was just missing the space after the bullet.