# Markdown stripping out line breaks in code block nested within list

Tags: bitbucket, markdown

I have the following code in a readme.me file on BitBucket:

````
# Instructions #
1. Add the following configuration element:

    ```
    {  
        "A": 1,  
        "B": 2,  
        "C": 3
    }  
    ```

2. Second list item
````

When I edit view the formatted output, the code block is correctly identified as code and is contained within the list item, but the line breaks within the code block are all removed, making it difficult to read.

However, if I remove one set of leading four spaces from the code block, the line breaks are preserved correctly, but the code block is no longer part of the list, causing the second list item to start over at #1, which is not desired:

````
# Instructions #
1. Add the following configuration element:

```
{  
    "A": 1,  
    "B": 2,  
    "C": 3
}  
```

2. Second list item
````

Is it possible to get a code block to format correctly within a list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should **indent the code block with 8 spaces** to preserve the ordering of the list, [as suggested by Chris under another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40709785/3151675).

```
# Instructions #
1. Add the following configuration element:

        {  
            "A": 1,  
            "B": 2,  
            "C": 3
        }

2. Second list item
```

This also indents the code block to appear like it's within the list:

[image: Screenshot of the result]

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work. It seems strange that it doesn't work with the backtick syntax, but I guess that doesn't matter if the end result is the same.

Comment: Bitbucket is rumored to use Python-Markdown. And Python-Markdown only supports fenced code blocks at the root level of the document. In other words, you can only use indented code blocks nested in a list.